# SharePoint Online: Bigger font weight for field titles on the form

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I would like to make the field titles bigger than the standard formating. Example below:
[image]
This is part of my body code:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, changing font size for column titles is *not possible* using JSON formatting capabilities.

> Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration **only allows defining one or more sections** and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

Body configuration does not support advance JSON customizations like header/footer (or column/view formatting in list views).

**Source**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)

---

You need to customize the list form using Power Apps to make changes to column titles for modern list forms.